# Compute the main diagonal of $(K + D)^{-1}$ in less than $O(n^3)$ operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

> Compute the main diagonal of $(K + D)^{-1}$ in less than $O(n^3)$ operations given full-rank, dense and symmetric matrices $K$ and $K^{-1}$, and a diagonal matrix $D$ with positive elements on its main diagonal.

I have tried this for a month and I can't manage to perform this operation in less than $O(n^3)$. I would also be happy knowing a proof or a clear indication that it is actually impossible.

Note: I assume we are using $O(n^3)$ for matrix product operations.

Comment: Is it well know what the complexity is for finding $(K + X)^{-1}$ when $X$ is rank $1$?

Comment: It is $O(n^2)$ when $K^{-1}$ is given [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far from new. Clearly, if $D$ is not small in front of $K$, then the knowledge of $K^{-1}$ adds nothing. If $K+D$ is sparse, then there is a recent method to solve approximately the problem; yet, here it is not the case.

Assume that $||K^{-1}D||<<1$. Then we can obtain an approximation of the diagonal of $(K+D)^{-1}$ in $O(n^2)$.

Proof.  It is not difficult to see that $(K+D)^{-1}=(I+K^{-1}D)^{-1}K^{-1}=K^{-1}-K^{-1}DK^{-1}+O(||K^{-1}D||^2)K^{-1}$. The diagonal of $K^{-1}DK^{-1}$ can be calculated in $O(n²)$.

Comment: Thank you. Still, that is not the case with my $K$ and $D$. I just find puzzling that knowing $n^2$ elements of the inverse seems to have the same computational cost (asymptotically) as knowing its diagonal only.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the inverse of an $n \times n$ matrix can be done faster than cubic time (i.e. $o(n^3)$). See this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) for instance. You therefore could compute the inverse directly.

Comment: It is only true if we use matrix product algorithms theoretically faster than $O(n^3)$, and that is why I mentioned that in my post (please, refer to the Note I left in my post).